What is the correct Range function in apps Script that will allow my code to run through every row individually?
I created a Google Spreadsheet that revolves around recurring events. The input for the recurring events are coded to populate my Google Calendar. When I run the code it works as it should except it only runs the first row. I know it has something to do with my Range argument. I have even been able to select which row I wanted to run by doing ss.getRange("what ever number row here",2).getValue(). But I have never been able to run all of the rows and I can not figure out how to do it.
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Pop").addItem("Create Event",
  "recurring_event").addToUi()
}
function recurring_event() {
  var row = 2
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ws.getSheetByName("sheet6")
  var title = ss.getRange(row, 1,1000).getValue()
  var start_date = ss.getRange(row, 2,1000).getValue()
  var duration = ss.getRange(row, 3,1000).getValue()
  var repetition = ss.getRange(row, 4,1000).getValue()

  var end_date = new Date(start_date)
  end_date.setTime(end_date.getTime()+1000*60*duration)

  var recurrence =""
  if(repetition=="3 Month") recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().
  addMonthlyRule().interval(3)
  else if(repetition=="6 Month") recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().
  addMonthlyRule().interval(6)
  else if(repetition=="annually") recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().
  addYearlyRule() 

  CalendarApp.createEventSeries(title, start_date, end_date,recurrence)
}

I have tried doing ss.getRange(2,3,1000).getValue hoping that it would return the next 1000 rows but it did not. I have also played with ss.getDataRange() but I don't know if I am doing it correctly. I just am lost as to what might be the next step.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample (Sample Sheet). This way the community will have an idea how your data looks like in Sheets.

From the question

I have tried doing ss.getRange(2,3,1000).getValue hoping that it would return the next 1000 rows but it did not.

The SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue method returns the value of only one cell, no matter how many cells have the range. To get the values of all cells in the range, instead use SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues.
Just so you know, you should update your script to handle the suggested method's response. For details about how to read and write values to Google Sheets, please see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

I actually have tried that and every time I have tried that I get this error "Exception: The parameters (String,number[],(class),String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.createEventSeries." So I thought it might be something wrong with my date arguments being strings but I think I did them correctly because when I go back to running them indivudually they run just fine.

@DevonLudwig, questions on this site should be as specific as yours. It asked about the SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue, and this answer answered that. The error you mentioned in the comment relates to a different question, and a follow-up question should be posted as a new question.
